# Can rapid change in direction of DC motor's rotation damage it?

Tags: motor

I am using a 12-24V 775 DC motor and changing its direction of rotation once every second for an hour will it damage the motor in long term?

Comment: It's probably a bit more demanding on the motor than just one direction. Though this can really be answered only by the manufacturer of the motor. If it's a good manufacturer it might have already tested different use scenarios. For here this is off topic since not about Arduino. Sorry

Comment: See "plug reversing" for the approach most likely to stress and damage the motor.

Comment: Sounds like a better job for a stepper motor.  Stepper won't care.

Comment: No problem doing so. Many of printer head feed motors are linear, fast reversing the direction, while lasts forever.

Comment: what driver or driver controls (current limit?) do you have in place and what's the max temp the motor reaches during that hour?  If you needed to burn out a loaded 24V motor in an hour of switching directions, you could certainly design and tune a driver to include an underlying signal at an appropriate frequency to do so without it being noticeable except as the motor overtemp- unlikely (not impossible with a shoddy psu) to get there accidentally though.

Comment: @chrisl - This question was just moved **from** Arduino site, and is appropriate for here. The true answer is that it all depends upon what the motor was designed for, and what it can take. OhmVaghela, you may go through several motors of escalating capabilities, or learn that you have to add special cooling, before you make it work. My suggestion. Look at what temp the motor is rated for, and use an infrared thermometer, keep an eye on it. And add the cooling that you'll probably need until temperature settles to what is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use a controlled acceleration and braking to change directions, something is being stressed at twice the normal surge current and twice the voltage from BEMF.  This also jerks mechanical parts and burns out your controller.

Neither is a healthy activity without a controlled start/stop/reverse causing excessive heat and likely damage.

Reversing the motor essentially every second essentially absorbs 10x the power during start and with back EMF on reverse , you have 2x the voltage and 4x the possible power being applied thus up to 40x the rated load power in bursts.

If however you used constant current  less than rated load current, during each reversal, with a suitable controller, then it can be done. But then the cycle rate would be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Your motor is likely to overheat due to the repeated current spikes from direction change. Brushes are likely to wear out much faster. This will definitely damage the motor in the long run.